# Unable to paste multi-line JSON string into environment variable in Eclipse run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to set a multi-line JSON string in environment variable under Run Configurations in eclipse IDE. However, it takes just the first line and discards all. For example, let's say I have a below JSON:

{"name":"apple",
"type":"fruit"}

When I am attempting to post the JSON into the environment variable, its just taking the first line alone as depicted below:

{"name":"apple",

However, it works absolutely fine in IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: It might be valuable to show *how* you’re attempting to do this. (And what “posting” means here.)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks for pointing it out, that was a typo. Have rectified it now. In Run Configurations dialog in Eclipse there is Environment variables tab. I am trying to add new variable there. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: What's the ultimate reason for caring if there's a newline in it? It's JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The run/launch configuration dialog does not support entering a multi-line string for an environment variable.

As workaround you can encode line breaks as `${system_property:line.separator}`, e.g. for your example:

```
{"name":"apple",${system_property:line.separator}"type":"fruit"}
```

You can do the replacing in an *Untitled Text File* via *Find and Replace* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) by replacing `\R` with `\${system_property:line.separator}` as *Regular Expression*.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't discard anything. Press OK as if it hasn't, because when you try to edit the value later, it'll all be there.